# How to place a button in the trailing part of the ListTitle in flutter

Tags: flutter, android-listview

I want to add a button in the end part of the listTile in my flutter project, and by clicking on the button I want to show a popup dialog box.

here is my code:

```
body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: imgPath.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Card(
                child: ListTile(
                  leading: CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundImage: NetworkImage(imgPath[index]),
                    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                  ),
                  title: Text(title[index]),
                  subtitle: Text(subtitle[index]),
                  trailing: Container(
                    // child: Text('Pending'),
                    width: 40,
                    // height: 70,
                    color: Colors.green,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          }

      )
```

I was taking Container() but I want to take a button there

Comment: Post screenshot, what you want exactly?

Comment: Your code looks right to me. Which error your are getting?

Comment: I wanted to add a raised button on the trailing part, is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

instead of taking a Container, use a IconButton it should work good

```dart
body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: imgPath.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Card(
                child: ListTile(
                  leading: CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundImage: NetworkImage(imgPath[index]),
                    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                  ),
                  title: Text(title[index]),
                  subtitle: Text(subtitle[index]),
                  trailing: IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.xxxx), onPressed: (){
                      //logic to open POPUP window
                  }),
                ),
              ),
            );
          }

      )
```

if you want some text there, then you can go with your container, and wrap it with a GestureDetector, like this

```dart
body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: imgPath.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Card(
                child: ListTile(
                  leading: CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundImage: NetworkImage(imgPath[index]),
                    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                  ),
                  title: Text(title[index]),
                  subtitle: Text(subtitle[index]),
                  trailing: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: (){
                         //logic to open POPUP window
                       }
                      child:Container(
                    // child: Text('Pending'),
                    width: 40,
                    // height: 70,
                    color: Colors.green,
                  ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          }

      )
```